# How to get controller name in cakephp (2.x) component?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Anybody can suggest me that how to get controller name in cakephp component function?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Router::getRequest(true)->param('controller');
```

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
 $ctrObj = $this->_Collection->getController();
```

#### Getting class name:

```
 $ctrName = get_class($ctrObj);
 die('<h1>Class name: ' . $ctrName . '</h1>');
 // Result: "Class name: FooController"
```

#### Getting simple name:

```
 $ctrName = $ctrObj->name;
 die('<h1>Simple Name: ' . $ctrName . '</h1>');
 // Result: "Simple Name: Foo"
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CakePHP very much, and possibly there is a built-in method for this. But if you are running PHP 5.5+, below code might give you inspiration

```
class Foo {
  public function name_of_this_controller() {
    return static::class;
  }
}

$f = new Foo();
echo $f->name_of_this_controller() #=> "Foo"
```

for older versions of php,

```
get_class($f)
```

will work.

So, inside components [(I am referring here)](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) assigning `static::class` to a variable will do work, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->request->params['controller']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->params['controller'] to get the current controller.`

You can do a `debug($this->params)` to see other available variables.

Comment: I Found one way, You can check this method to get controller name in component: 
$currentURL = Router::url( $this->here, true ); 
        $myurl = parse_url($currentURL);
        $split = explode("/",$myurl['path']);
        $controllerName = ucfirst($split[2]);